# localhost is appending to RequestURL while $http.post using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using json-server(https://github.com/typicode/json-server) as a mock server.My json server runs @ 127.0.0.1:3001. When i am trying to post data to that json server using $http.post() from my application which runs at localhost:3000. Its posting like http://localhost:3000/127.0.0.1:3001/tasks/....

When i look some other posts they were suggesting to enable CORS at server end. But i donno how to enable CORS to json server. Can any1 help me out for this.

Code:

```
 return $http.post(config.baseURL+"/tasks"+app,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);
```

Kindly help. config.baseURL has 127.0.0.1:3001.
PFA Screenshot too[image]
Looking forward for help from techies...

Comment: Well, set your config.baseURL to `http://127.0.0.1:3001`, not to `127.0.0.1:3001`. The documentation of the server says that CORS and JSONP are enabled by default.

Comment: Hi JB..Its already holding same as you said.. With that baseurl only I got this output..kindly help if u know solution for this

Comment: Re-read my comment, and re-read your question and code. You said it's set to `127.0.0.1:3001`. That's incorrect. It must be set to `http://127.0.0.1:3001`. That's quite different. Also, if you want help with non-working code, you MUST post the code.

Comment: Ok let me cross check JB. Give me a moment..